# how do i use this linq query to display data in MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How do i display key and count data in cshtml

This is class:

```
      public class ViewModelData
       {
         public int Key { get; set; }
         public int Count { get; set; }
       }
```

This is Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Trigger()
       {
        var result = repository.Paths.GroupBy(x => x.SmokeCar)
                                    .Select(x => new ViewModelData
                                    {
                                        Key = x.Key,
                                        Count = x.Count()
                                    }).ToList();

        return View(result);
         }
```

this is cshtml

```
      @model IEnumerable CessationPath.Domain.Entities.ViewModelData
          <div>
        <span>Count:</span>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the collection passed and print it.

```
@model IEnumerable<CessationPath.Domain.Entities.ViewModelData>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        @item.Key.ToString()
        <span> Count: @item.Count.ToString()</span>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: It says type or namespace item cannot be found? Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

To display a count of records:

```
@model IEnumerable<CessationPath.Domain.Entities.ViewModelData>
<div>
    <span>Count:</span> @Model.Count()
</div>
```

Then to display the contents of each record:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <li>@item.Key, @item.Count</li>
}
</ul>
```